# My edit page doesnt edit the rows

Tags: php, mysql, edit

I have 2 buttons on my table which delete and edit data from the table, (data from the database) the delete button works well but the edit isnt working.. It runs like it is working but when I list the data it is like I created in the PhpMyadmin..
here is the main edit code:

```
<?php
// Editar um registo de user
if (isset($_GET['editequip']) == False) {
// Caso seja chamado directamente na URL o ficheiro "editar.php",
// este é redireccionado para o ficheiro "lista.php"
header("location:javascript:history.go(-1);return false;;");
} else {
$editequip = trim($_GET['editequip']);
}   
$connection = new mysqli('***', '****', '****', '****');
$obterequip = "SELECT * FROM fichas WHERE id_ficha LIKE '$editequip'";
$resultequip = $connection->query($obterequip);
// Se devolveu 0 ou mais do que um utilizador, termina script
if ($connection->affected_rows != 1) {
header("location:javascript:history.go(-1);return false;");
exit();
}
$objequip = $resultequip->fetch_object();
$id_ficha = $objequip->id_ficha;
$id_user = $objequip->id_user;
$avaria = $objequip->avaria;
$observacoes = $objequip->observacoes;
$observacoes_privadas = $objequip->observacoes_privadas;
$estado = $objequip->estado;

?> <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
<title>Edição de Equipamentos</title></head>
<body>
<div id="links">
<a href="http://www.numica.pt"> Voltar ao site</a> |
<a href="restrito"> Ínicio</a> |
<a href="lista"> Utilizadores</a> |
<a href="fileupload/index"> Upload de Ficheiros</a> |
<a href="logout.php"> Logout</a>
</div>
<h1>Editar Estado</h1>
<div id="container"><div class="left">
<form action="updatequip.php" method="post" id="editar">    
<input type="hidden" name="ificha" value="<?php echo $id_ficha ?>"/>
<label>ID da Ficha: </label> <?php echo $id_ficha ?> <br>
<label>ID do Cliente: </label><input type="text" name="iuser" value="<?php echo $id_user ?>"><br>
<label>Avaria: </label><input type="text" name="iavaria" value="<?php echo $avaria ?>"><br>
<label>Observações: </label><input type="text" name="iobservacoes"value="<?php echo $observacoes ?>"><br>
<label>Observações Privadas: </label><input type="text" name="iobservacoes_privadas" value="<?php echo $observacoes_privadas?>"><br>
<label>Estado</label><input type="text" name="iestado" value="<?php echo $estado ?>"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Alterar"/>
<input type="button" value="Cancelar"onclick="javascript:history.go(-1);return false;"/>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <p>Copyright © 2013 - Todos os direitos reservados - <a href="mailto:numica@numica.pt">Númica</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the action page:

```
<?php
    // Inserir o registo na BD
    include_once ('config1.php');

    // Estabelecer a ligação à BD
    $connection = new mysqli('*****', '*****', '*******', '***');

    //Verificar se a ligação foi estabelecida com sucesso
    if (mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
        echo "</h2>Erro no acesso a BD</h2>" . mysqli_connect_error(); 

        exit();
        }
// Validar se os campos do formulário foram preenchidos pelo utilizador
// Verificar se "username" foi enviado
if (isset($_POST['ificha']) == FALSE) {
echo ("Erro de submissão no ida da ficha");
exit();
} else {
$id_ficha = trim($_POST['ificha']);
}
if (isset($_POST['iuser']) == FALSE) {
echo ("Erro de submissão do id do user");
exit();
} else {
$id_user = trim($_POST['iuser']);
}
if (isset($_POST['iavaria']) == FALSE) {
echo ("Erro de submissão da avaria");
exit();
} else {
$avaria = trim($_POST['iavaria']);
}
if (isset($_POST['iobservacoes']) == FALSE) {
echo ("Erro de submissão nas observacoes");
exit();
} else {
$observacoes = trim($_POST['iobservacoes']);
}
if (isset($_POST['iobservacoes_privadas']) == FALSE) {
echo ("Erro de submissão nas observacoesprivadas");
exit();
} else {
$observacoes_privadas = trim($_POST['iobservacoes_privadas']);
}
if (isset($_POST['iestado']) == FALSE) {
echo ("Erro de submissão no estado");
exit();
} else {
$estado = trim($_POST['iestado']);
}

 // Final das validações (avisa caso algum erro seja detectado)
if ($erro) {
echo "<p>Formulário submetido com erros</p>";
echo $msgerro;
echo "<br>";
// Desenha 2 botões "Corrigir" e "Listar"
echo "<a class='ains' href='javascript:history.go(-1)' title='Volta à página anterior'>Corrigir </a>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<a class='ains' href='verificarequipamentos.php'>Listar</a>";
exit();
}
$sql = "UPDATE fichas SET
            id_user = '$id_user';
            avaria = '$avaria';
            observacoes = '$observacoes';
            observacoes_privadas = '$observacoes_privadas';
            estado = '$estado';
            WHERE
            id_ficha = '$id_ficha'";
$connection->query($sql);
// Lista users depois de actualizar
header("location:verificarequipamentos.php");

?>
```

Comment: You should probably remove all those semicolons from the UPDATE query.

Comment: It's working by replacing the semicolons for commas, sorry for this little detail

Comment: My mistake - I should have mentioned that in my comment. I should go back and edit it so it looks like I was right all along....

Comment: Yep, commas are what you want here. It's worth adding some error handling, so this error is reported, rather than just failing silently.

Comment: type in the answer so I can aprove it, it might help someone with that same mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the semicolons to comas on the update query Or concat the variables with dots, You shoud also use a framework for this kind of things, it could be much easier.

Comment: I already tried a framework but since I don't have many experience programming I didnt knew how to use it and I didnt have many time to learn it to this work so had to work without one

Comment: Well if you want to continue using php when you feel ready, i recomend codeigniter [link]http://ellislab.com/codeigniter es the least confusing and yet can do much, this tutorials are great too [link] https://www.phpacademy.org/